Copy files from source directory to destination directory, following symlinks in destination directory
I'm trying to copy some files from one directory to another and resolve all symlinks in the destination directory. To better illustrate what I'm saying, my source directory looks something like this:
source
  |-- dir1
  |     `-- file1
  |-- dir2
  |     |-- dir4
  |     `-- file2
  `-- dir3
        `-- file3

And the destination directory:
dest
  |-- dir1
  |-- dir2 -> dir1
  `-- dir3

I want to copy files from source to dest recursively so that after the operation, the destination directory looks like this:
dest
  |-- dir1
  |     |-- dir4
  |     |-- file1
  |     `-- file2
  |-- dir2 -> dir1
  `-- dir3
        `-- file3

I am currently attempting to do this with cp -R source/. dest/ (I can't use the shell glob * for other reasons), and it fails with the error cp: target dest/./dir2 is not a directory. How can I achieve the desired result?
Edit: cannot assume that all directories in source exist in dest.
Edit 2: I could possibly achieve this by creating a tarball of source and extracting it to dest. But that feels really clunky and adding unnecessary steps.

Please [edit] your question and confirm that all directory names in source also exist in dest. Or state if this is not the case and the copying is expected to create directories.

No, not all directory names in source already exist in dest. I have edited my question

It would be good to modify the example to include a case of a directory from source  that is missing in dest.

You could use tar without writing to a file. cd /path/to/source; tar cf - . | ( cd /path/to/dest; tar xf - ) or with GNU tar tar -C /path/to/source -cf - . | tar -C /path/to/dest -xpf -.

I suggest to use find:
cd /path/to/source
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /path/to/dest/{} \; -o -type f -exec cp {} /path/to/dest/{} \;

(The part for creating directories was added after the question was edited to clarify that directories might not exist in dest.)

This works if all directories in source exist in dest, but as you pointed out this isn't necessarily the case.

@AVSOrigami updated to create directories in one find command

I found a method based on @Bodo's solution involving find:
cd source
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p ../dest/{} \;
find . -type f -exec cp {} ../dest/{} \;

Basically just creates the directories first if they don't exist, then uses the find method to copy them.
